# Need circuit to permit the lowest frequency of two input signals and stop the other one (audio)

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, flipflop

I am working on a paraphonic signal processor which shifts the pitch of an incoming note down by a full octave. It's a relatively simple principle which I know well (Flip Flop divide down frequency) but the input of this is going to be presented with two discrete input sources - i.e. two different notes. I need to allow the lowest note to pass, and the higher one to be gated/not permitted to pass into the circuit.

So basically, if two notes are played - an E at 83Hz and an A at 110Hz, I need to allow the 83Hz signal to pass, and the 110Hz to not. Conversely, if *only* the 110Hz is present, this signal needs to pass (and the other one to be muted to prevent interruption - though this is optional, and not quite so important).

I'm hoping to keep the component count low for this so I would appreciate the simplest principle application here, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider doing this with a signal processor? I think it will work much better.

Comment: what type of signal is being switched?

Comment: @mkeith - I am trying to keep this analog. It may be an option if I can't find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @jsotola - when you say type of signal, what do you mean? it's a line level input of a sinewave.

Comment: @TCassa analog or digital ... now I see it is analog

Comment: @TCassa using a flip flop to divide a frequency means you're not *really* doing this analog, anyway: your discretizing amplitude to feed it into the flip-flop, and the flip-flop handles your signal as discrete in time, so congratulations, while claiming this is an analog solution, you basically invented a digital system :) So, yeah, this is easy with a digital signal processor, which these days means "basically any 1-2 € ARM microcontroller with at least 2 ADC channels".

Comment: what is the source of the two signals ... the main problem is that it takes time to detect which frequency is lower ... that delay may be unacceptable in music performance ... is there any way to determine which frequencies are about to be played?

Answer (score 4):

Using a flip flop to divide a frequency means you're not really doing this analog, anyway: your discretizing amplitude to feed it into the flip-flop, and the flip-flop handles your signal as discrete in time, so congratulations, while claiming this is an analog solution, you basically invented a digital system!

So, yeah, this is easy with a digital signal processor, which these days means "basically any 1-2 € ARM microcontroller with at least 2 ADC channels".

That would put your component count to 9 to 11:

- 1 Microcontroller
- 2 R + 2 C for one RC antialiasing filter and one RC reconstruction filter
- a dual opamp (optionally) to drive your filter and ADC and to buffer the output
- 1 or 2 decoupling capacitors

assuming your microcontroller has a sufficient DAC; else, add a DAC (and a decoupling capacitor) to the equation.

The rest is classical digital signal processing: use a Welch detector to detect your dominant tone, and a linear-phase FIR filter to blank the recessive tone on detection.

Latency might be a problem: to determine whether a tone of 120 Hz is played, you'll really need to observe for at least half a period, more realistically 1 to 10 periods. This means you might very well incur a significant time difference between onset of dominant tone and muting of the other.

You'll also want to delay your signal by half the length of the blanking FIR filter when passing it through – that's the filter's group delay, and you'd make temporal "jumps" whenever you switch between blanking and non-blanking otherwise. (That's not a special "problem" of the digital filter: an analog filter has a group delay, too, just that we can't make it constant over all frequencies as in a digital filter, necessitating way more effort on mode switch than the digital approach.)